# Find partial occurences in data frame based on a vector

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, data.table, sql-like

I've got a dataframe `a` and a vector `b` (derived from another data frame). Now I want to find all occurences from vector `b` in `a`.
However, unfortunately vector `b` sometimes misses a leading character.

```
a <- structure(list(GSN_IDENTITY_CODE = c("01234567", "65461341", "NH1497", "ZH0080", "TP5146", "TP5146"), PIG_ID = c("129287133", "120561144", "119265685", "121883198", "109371743", "109371743" ), SEX_CODE = c("Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "B", "B")), .Names = c("GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", "PIG_ID", "SEX_CODE"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> a
#      IDENTITY_CODE    PIG_ID SEX_CODE
#1          01234567 129287133        Z
#2          65461341 120561144        Z
#3            NH1497 119265685        Z
#4            ZH0080 121883198        Z
#5            TP5146 109371743        B
#6            TP5146 109371743        B

b <- c("65461341", "1234567", "ZH0080", "TP5146")
```

My expected output would be this:

```
a
#  GSN_IDENTITY_CODE    PIG_ID SEX_CODE
#1          01234567 129287133        Z
#2          65461341 120561144        Z
#4            ZH0080 121883198        Z
#5            TP5146 109371743        B
```

When first removing the duplicates it solves one problem, however I still need a way to select all rows containing the values from vector `b` whereas I need more rows:

```
a <- a[!duplicated(a$GSN_IDENTITY_CODE),]
```

---

Unfortunately I cannot use `%in%` because it will bring in duplicates and miss out on the first line because it does not accept regex':

```
> a[a$GSN_IDENTITY_CODE %in% b,]
#  GSN_IDENTITY_CODE    PIG_ID SEX_CODE
#2          65461341 120561144        Z
#4            ZH0080 121883198        Z
#5            TP5146 109371743        B
#6            TP5146 109371743        B
```

Using `data.table`'s `%like%` would work only for the first string in vector `b`

```
library(data.table)
> setDT(a)
> a[a$GSN_IDENTITY_CODE %like% b,]
#   GSN_IDENTITY_CODE    PIG_ID SEX_CODE
#1:          65461341 120561144        Z
Warning message:
In grepl(pattern, vector) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there a function in R that supports my needs here?

---

@Frank's attempt yields the following error:

```
a <- structure(list(GSN_IDENTITY_CODE = c("01234567", "65461341", "NH1497", "ZH0080", "TP5146", "TP5146"), PIG_ID = c("129287133", "120561144", "119265685", "121883198", "109371743", "109371743" ), SEX_CODE = c("Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "B", "B")), .Names = c("GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", "PIG_ID", "SEX_CODE"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

b <- c("65461341", "1234567", "ZH0080", "TP5146")

> a[.(b), on="GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", nomatch=FALSE, mult="first"]
Error in `[.data.frame`(a, .(b), on = "GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", nomatch = FALSE,  : 
  unused arguments (on = "GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", nomatch = FALSE, mult = "first")
> setDT(a)
> a[.(b), on="GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", nomatch=FALSE, mult="first"]
Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  x.'GSN_IDENTITY_CODE' is a character column being joined to i.'NA' which is type 'NULL'. Character columns must join to factor or character columns.
```

Comment: What about `a[grepl(paste(b, collapse = "|"), x = a$GSN_IDENTITY_CODE), ]` and removing duplicates? This obviously has some pitfalls, but can be somewhat alleviated.

Comment: Key to life is not to be confined to your imagination. :) Good luck.

Comment: If you downvote, at least have the courtesy to comment why, so I can improve my future questions.

Comment: I'm curious, is `1234567` suppose to match? It's not in the expected output and you mention "unfortunately vector `b` sometimes misses a leading character." which makes me think you want it to be matched.

Comment: @Roman `1234567` in vector `b` occurs in `01234567` in `a[1,1,]`. So I want `a[1,1]` to be in my new data frame

Comment: Right, can you modify the expected result?

Comment: Wait for fuzzy matching or install a package that supports it. If you want vanilla matching... `a[.(b), on="GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", nomatch=FALSE, mult="first"]`. You could consider cleaning your data instead of fuzzy matching, of course.

Comment: @Roman wow I completely missed the incorrect expected output, shame on me. updated it.

Comment: @Frank I will try your solution in the morning, unfortunately I'm getting the data delivered in these formats so I can't really clean the data myself:(

Comment: @Frank I just tried your solution, unfortunately it doesn't work. I've posted the error in my question

Comment: @Bas Oh, sorry, I assumed you had `a` as a data.table already. Use `setDT(a)` (without an `<-`) on it first. By the way, you posted the code but not the error, so I'm just guessing that you're seeing the same error that I am.

Comment: @Frank I updated my question with the errors, both before and after using `setDT()`

Comment: Ok, I guess the version I'm using has simpler syntax. You could try `a[.(GSN_IDENTITY_CODE = b), on="GSN_IDENTITY_CODE", nomatch=FALSE, mult="first"]` but I'm not sure that'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this for close matches if the extra character might occur anywhere in the string:

```
library(stringdist)
library(purrr)


a$closest_match <- map(a$GSN_IDENTITY_CODE, ~stringdist(., b, method = "lv")) %>% 
  map_dbl(min)
a[a$closest_match < 2, ]
```

If the extra character is always at the beginning, I would do something like this:

```
library(stringr)

a$stripped_code <- str_replace(a$GSN_IDENTITY_CODE,"^\\d", "")

a$keep <- a$GSN_IDENTITY_CODE %in% b | a$stripped_code %in% b
a[a$keep, ]
```